# Can i use wildcard bash alias for SSH

Tags: shell, unix

I have list of hostnames start with web1,web2,...,web200,web201.myserver.ltd etc

I already used in .ssh/config:

```
Host *
    User myuser
```

and in resolv.conf:

```
search myserver.ltd
```

So instead of using `ssh myuser@web200.myserver.ltd` i can use `ssh web200`

The question: is there any way that i can set a wildcard alias in my .zshrc file so when i type web200, it'll execute ssh web200? (and the same applies for any server that starts with webxxx.

I know that i can set that by using separate alias for each webxxx server, but i'm looking for one line (or few lines) way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With zsh, you can use a [`command_not_found_handler` hook](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Command-Execution.html):

```
command_not_found_handler () {
[[ $1 = web* ]] && ssh "$@"
}
```

Then:

```
$ web200
ssh: Could not resolve hostname web200: Temporary failure in name resolution
zsh: command not found: web200
```

Comment: Great answer.  This would work in Bash as well.  See this post: https://superuser.com/questions/787424/hook-into-command-not-found-handler-in-ubuntu